# find and replace data on gzip content efficiently

Tags: c, gzip

my c linux based program inputs are:

```
char *in_str, char *find_str, char *replacing_str
```

the `in_str` is a compressed data (gzip).

the program needs to find for the `find_str` within the uncompressed input data, replace it with `replacing_str`, and then to recompress the data.

the trivial way to do so is by using one of the many available gzip compress/uncompress libraries to uncompress the data, manipulate the uncompressed data, and then to recompress the output. However i need to make it as efficient as possible (it is a RT program).

i wonder if it is more efficient to use an on-the-fly library (e.g. zlibc) approach or simply do the operation as described above.

maybe it is important to mention that:

- the find_str and replacing_str strings are a small portion of the data
- their lengths are not equal
- the find_str supposed to appear about 4 or 5 times
- the uncompressed data len is ~2K - 6K bytes

does anyone familiar with an efficient way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to implement a caching scheme.  If a particular file is decompressed keep the decompressed (and modified) text for a while.  Then subsequent requests do not need to decompress it.  When a particular threshold of caching space is reached the decompressed files could be recompressed with the one that was used the longest ago being done first.  For some types of use this could be a real plus, for instance if the activity is bursty and asynchronus

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to decompress no matter what, in order to search for the strings.  (You might be able to get away with doing that only once and building an index.  However that might be much larger than the uncompressed data, so you might as well just store it uncompressed instead.)

You can avoid recompressing all of it by preparing the gzip file ahead of time to be compressed in smaller historyless units using, for example, the `Z_FULL_FLUSH` option of zlib.  This will reduce compression slightly depending on how often you do it, but will speed up building the output greatly if only one of many blocks need to be recompressed.